# If url is root domain add class (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I want to check is the user is on: http://www.stack.net or http://www.stack.net/ or http://www.stack.net/index or http://www.stack.net/index.php

If one of these variables match, I want to add a class. I'm searching to work this with PHP. From the other pages i was using that:

```
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'active';
}
```

HTML

```
 <li class="nav-item <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("inscripciones")?>" id="inscripciones-item-menu">
```

That's work when the user isn't on the root domain, but if he is in the root domain I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: are you able to get the urls ` http://www.stack.net/`, `http://www.stack.net/index.php`, etc ??

Comment: With index.php yes, because I call to the name of the file. But if the url is stack.net, stack.net/ I'm having problems because there is no name of file in the url.

Comment: You should apply a SEO solution first: Canonize the URLs that point to the same resource using permanent redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    $last_part = rtrim($last_part ,"/");         // removing trailing slash if present
    $last_part = end(split('/',$current_url ));  // getting last part of url

    // now you can validate this add class names 
}
```

The `$last_part` can be a file name, or even a directory name

**Edit:**

So now you can have a function like:

```
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    // validation logic

    if (your condition)
        echo 'active';
    else           // optional
        echo ''; 
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
<li class="nav-item <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("inscripciones")?>" id="inscripciones-item-menu">
```

Comment: What I need to insert in the HTML? this? <li class="nav-item <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>" id="home-item-menu">

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga yes you can. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")`.

This will give you `/index.php` if you are in the root.